# Which one is correct "a question of something" or "a question about something"?

Tags: word-usage

I think most people use "a question of something", ex: a question of energy

Some non-native students say "a question about something", ex: a question about energy.

Does native say "**a question about something**"?

Comment: [A question of fact](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_of_fact) this is.

Answer (score 2):

They mean different things.

"I have a question about interest rates" means that I want to ask a question, and the subject of the question is 'interest rates'.

"The Fed has to consider the question of interest rates" means that the Fed has to *consider the issue* of interest rates.

See [definition 2](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/question) - A subject or point that is under discussion or open to controversy; A matter of concern or difficulty; a problem